# Importing a Site Collection as a Subsite in powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a site collection that has subsites underneath it, and I want to move the entire collection so it's a subsite of another site. Thing is, the URL site collection I want to move is the same URL that I want the new subsite to be. I researched how to basically do this with powershell scripts, but I'm lost as to how to get my current site collection, which isn't a subsite of my site, to be imported as a subsite of my site with the same URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Michael

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I've not done anything like this in IIS 7+. In IIS 6, this is non-trivial. It may be as simple as you make it sound in IIS 7.

There are a dozen ways to do this if you're only doing it once or twice. Probably the easiest is to export the virtual directories off as XML and import the XML back into your new site. If you're planning to reuse whatever process you create, then maybe it's worth the time to learn PowerShell and generate a script, but consider approaching the problem in some simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Found an interesting article in this blog:

http://www.tcsc.com/move-a-site-collection-to-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2010/

I think that is what you are looking for.

Summary of the article is:

1. Export the site collection

   Export-SPWeb -Identity https://portal.contoso.com/sites/MoveMe -Path “C:MoveMe.bak” -IncludeUserSecurity -Compression 1024 -IncludeVersions 4
2. Create a new subsite

   New-SPWeb -URL https://portal.contoso.com/sites/NewHome/MoveMe
3. Import the Exported Site Collection

   https://portal.contoso.com/sites/NewHome/MoveMe -Path “C:MoveMe.bak”
4. Delete the Old Site Collection

   Remove-SPSite -Identity https://portal.contoso.com/sites/MoveMe